# How to link ckeditor in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to attach Ckeditor using angularjs, can anyone tell me how to give plugin for that? I am new to angularjs
     thank you in advance

Comment: have you take  a look to this? https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor

Comment: https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor

Comment: Please search before posting. The solution for your question is literally the first result for "angular ckeditor" on any major search engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is already plugin written for AngularJS to use CKEditor using custom directive declaration.

Converting texarea into CKEditor can be achieved with just one line of code:

```
<textarea ckeditor="editorOptions" ng-model="modelName"></textarea>
```

Adding dependency:

```
// add dependency
angular.module('app', ['ngCkeditor'])

// setup editor options
$scope.editorOptions = {
    language: 'ru',
    uiColor: '#000000'
};
```

Please find more details on plugin repository documentation
https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor